Pulsar MoP - MQTT - Port 1883 Connection Refused - When Both Pulsar and Client are in separate Docker containers
I have pulsar in one container and docker in another container.
I am using docker desktop.
Scenario 1: Mosquitto Broker in one docker container and Mosquitto Client in another.
This works fine and I am able to do MQTT pub sub.
This rules out docker or firewall issues.
Scenario 2: Pulsar inside docker and Java client using Eclipse Paho on the host machine.
This also works fine and the MQTT pub sub is happening.
Problem Scenario 3: Pulsar inside docket container and Java client inside another docker container.
I have ensured that both are on the same docker network.
I have used the following config:
"messagingProtocols=mqtt protocolHandlerDirectory=./protocols mqttListeners=mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883 authorizationEnabled=false"
I am getting a "Connection Refused Error" and I see on network inspect and in the error message that the port and IP are absolutely correct of Pulsar. The DNS resolution is fine.
Why is Pulsar refusing the connection ?
Here are the details:
1.
Note in the below log of the java client that the IP address and port are resolved correctly to that of the pulsar container but only the connection is refused:
2024-11-06 16:20:12 2024-11-06 10:50:12,526 ERROR [io.ver.mqt.imp.MqttClientImpl] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) Can't connect to 172.23.0.2:1883 : io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /172.23.0.2:1883
2. The docker compose file is as below:

services:
  pulsar:
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar:3.3.1
    container_name: pulsar
    environment:
      - PULSAR_MEM=-Xms2g -Xmx2g
    networks:
      - pulsar-network
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
    volumes:
      - ./settings.txt:/tmp/settings.txt
    command: >
      sh -c "cat /tmp/settings.txt >> /pulsar/conf/broker.conf && bin/pulsar standalone"

  quarkus-app:
    image: openjdk:17-jdk-alpine
    container_name: quarkus-app
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    environment:
      - MQTT_HOST=pulsar
    depends_on:
      - pulsar
    networks:
      - pulsar-network
    volumes:
      - ./target/simple-mqtt-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar:/app/application.jar
      - ./target/application.properties:/app/config/application.properties
    command: >
      sh -c "sleep 20 && java -jar /app/application.jar"
    working_dir: /app
  
  mosquitto-client:
    image: alpine:latest
    container_name: mosquitto-client
    command: sh -c "apk add --no-cache mosquitto-clients && tail -f /dev/null"

networks:
  pulsar-network:
    external: false
    driver: bridge

3.the broker.conf of pulsar has the additions as below:
# MQTT Settings
messagingProtocols=mqtt
mqttListeners=mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883
mqttAdvertisedListeners=mqtt://pulsar:1883
authorizationEnabled=false
authenticationEnabled=false

In the client, we are using the broker url as:



private final String brokerUrl = "tcp://pulsar:1883";

Should we use tcp or mqtt here ? We have tried both but of no help.


